Convert data to hyperlink Docx using Nodejs
I want convert data to hyperlink:
Go to website Click here
=>>
This is my code:
router.post("/export-to-docx-1", function (req, res) {
const id = req.body.id;
const path1 = D:\\BaoCao.docx;
const content = fs.readFileSync(
path.resolve(__dirname, path1),
"binary"
);
const zip = new PizZip(content);
const doc = new Docxtemplater(zip, {
paragraphLoop: true,
linebreaks: true,
nullGetter
});
Report.findOne({articleID: id}, function (err, report) {
    if (report) {
        const data = {
            title: report.title,
            createdDate: report.createdDate,
            source: report.source,
            sectionsColumTrue: [],
            sectionsColumFalse: [],
        };
      
        doc.setData(data);
        doc.render();
        const buf = doc.getZip().generate({
            type: "nodebuffer",
            compression: "DEFLATE",
        });
        res.set({
            'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
            'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="report.docx"'
        });
        res.send(Buffer.from(buf));
        console.log("Export thành công");
    } else {
    }
})

});
